# Interacting with "Klarna checkout" radio button/field using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, visual-studio-code, klarna

I'm trying to interact with the field of Klarna Checkout on a website, but I'm not able to change the selected radio buttons nor enter information in the credit card fields. I'm using VS code, Python and selenium webdriver.

The website destination is: https://voltfashion.com/no/functional/kassen/
You need to add an item in order to see the "Klarna checkout section".
It is a Norwegian website.

I have tried some different coding solutions, but none of them worked. I didn't have any problems interacting with the other elements of the website, just the Klarna checkout section. Any suggestions?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Some of the code I've tried:

```
cardForm = driver.find_element_by_id("cardNumber")
cardForm.send_keys('1234567890987654')
```

and

```
inputCC = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until\
    (lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath\
        ("//input[@id='cardNumber']")
)
inputCC.send_keys("1234567890987654")
```

Klarna screenshot ([Source](https://crystallize.com/learn/open-source/payment-gateways/klarna)):

[image]

Comment: you have to add url to real html so we could see it in browser

Comment: maybe element is in `iframe` and it needs `switch_to_frame`, or maybe elements are hidden and it display some replacements. But we can't check it without url to real HTML.

Comment: @furas The website is in Norwegian, so that's why I was a little hesitant to add it (in case nobody was able to navigate it due to the languanga barrier). Here is the website: [link](https://voltfashion.com/no/functional/kassen/). You have to add an item before you are able to visit the "Klarna checkout section"

Comment: add this to question so other people could see it - and then other people can help you.

Comment: It seems this part is in `<iframe id="pgw-iframe-paynow_card">` so it needs to use `driver.switch_to.frame()`

Comment: @furas I've tried the "driver.switch_to.frame()", but maybe I did it wrong. Could you please give me a short specific code snippet which insert a number into the credit card field? So that I could test and know that I didn't do anything wrong.

Comment: I would have to create minimal working code for this - and this means code which put item in cart, fill form, etc. It is long code.

Comment: @furas No worries! Thank you for taking the time to answer :)